# Display old value and new value on forms and grids

Tags: forms, input-fields, information-architecture

In my application if user modifies the existing value then we need to show the previous value (existing) and also the modified value. The same feature is also needed for fields which are in the grids. I am trying in different approaches but not giving me a 100% sure.

Form field which we need to show the previous value and new values are as following:

1. Text Field
2. Dropdowns
3. Pick fields
4. Date picker
5. Check box
6. Radio button

I have below ideas to achieve above requirement, but when it comes to checkbox and radio buttons none of the below ideas won't work.

**Option A:**
When field is modified the orange bar appears beside(left side) to indicate the corresponding field updated.

[image]

When clicked on orange bar a popover appear in which user can see previous value of the field.
[image]

visual cue on grid:
[image]

**Option B:** As soon as user override value in the field the previous value will appear beside the field with strike through. **In this approach also I am not sure how to deal with checkboxes and radio buttons**.

**Form:**
[image]

Grid control:

[image]

Any other best solution we have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what the context of this is and assuming there is always just 1 previous value and it is important to the user to see both values, I would prefere option b.

The reason is, that a user is not forced to click to show the previous value. But there are some difficulties.
How does the input process work?
At what point is the previous value shown (beginning of typing, lost focus etc.)?

Radio buttons: show the radio button group strike through the old value and make it red, set the new value green.

[image]

If you go for option A, keep in mind that the orange indicator has to be large enough in order to be clickable easily.
[image]

Comment: I like this idea, and i agree we need to keep the shape large enough to be clickable.